# where is the exact certificate required for my curl commands

Tags: python, curl, ssl-certificate

I have a python application which talks to JIRA APIs through emulating curl commands. take for an instance a curl command given below

```
curl -E mpadakan -X GET -H 'Accept:application/json' 'https://track-api.company.com/jira/rest/api/2/issue/EPMENGG-2329'
```

Now notice the string mpadakan after the -E option. it's my company Id and the command automatically fetches the required certificates for curl. This works fine in my local host but now i need to host this on a server for production.

I've tried deleting the files in the .ssh and .certs directory in my home folder but the command still works even without these folder and the files in them.
How do i migrate this to my server now? Thanks in advance

Comment: install ca-certificates package

Comment: Could you please break that down a bit? @YOU